# How to provide mock values in a FeedResponse for CosmosSDK v3+?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, nsubstitute

I'm writing a data access layer for my application and trying to mock out the CosmosDB SDK dependency for unit testing. I am using NUnit with NSubstitute and have come across the issue where I am trying to mock the return values for Container.GetItemQueryIterator.

I have successfully provided a mock feedIterator as a response for that call and a mock feedResponse as a return value for feedIterator.ReadNextAsync, but I cannot figure out how to inject any sort of values into the FeedResponse to test against

The code I'm trying to test looks like this:

```cs
var feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(queryDefinition);

  while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults){
    result.success = true;

    foreach (var item in await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync()){
      list.Add(item);
    }
  }
```

My attempt at mocking out the dependencies like this (Simplified):

```cs
this.mockFeedResponse = Substitute.For<FeedResponse<T>>(this.mockApplicationList);         
this.mockFeedIterator = Substitute.For<FeedIterator<T>>();
this.mockFeedIterator.ReadNextAsync().ReturnsForAnyArgs(Task.FromResult(this.mockFeedResponse));
this.mockFeedIterator.HasMoreResults.Returns(true);
```

Looking at the AzureCosmosDB SDK documentation, there seems to be a  FeedResponse constructor for mocking that takes an IEnumerable as a parameter, but NSubstitute complains telling me it can't find this constructor when I attempt to pass in a list to use. Is there an alternative that I can feed some IEnumerable as a FeedResponse? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth - I worked around this by changing my code to access the Resource field on the FeedResponse received from CosmosDB. In my tests, I was able to then mock the return value for Resource and get the desired result.

Answer (score 19):

I also managed the issue by mocking the `GetEnumerator` call on the `FeedResponse` mock. However, something to keep in mind is that if you just set `mockFeedIterator.HasMoreResults(true)`, you'll end up in an infinite loop.

I solved that problem by using Moq's `Callback` method feature. I configured the `HasMoreResults` method to return true, and then setup a callback on the `ReadNextAsync` method to reconfigure `HasMoreResults` to return false. That way, it will drop into the `while` loop the first time, populate the return collection based on the mocked `GetEnumerator` method, and then exit the loop and return that collection to the test method.

```
var myItems = new List<MyItem>
{
    new MyItem(),
    new MyItem()
};

var feedResponseMock = new Mock<FeedResponse<MyItem>>();
feedResponseMock.Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(myItems.GetEnumerator());

var feedIteratorMock = new Mock<FeedIterator<MyItem>>();
feedIteratorMock.Setup(f => f.HasMoreResults).Returns(true);
feedIteratorMock
    .Setup(f => f.ReadNextAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(feedResponseMock.Object)
    .Callback(() => feedIteratorMock
        .Setup(f => f.HasMoreResults)
        .Returns(false));

var containerMock = new Mock<Container>();
containerMock
    .Setup(c => c.GetItemQueryIterator<MyItem>(
        It.IsAny<QueryDefinition>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<QueryRequestOptions>()))
    .Returns(feedIteratorMock.Object);
```

Comment: I found an easier way to change the HasMoreResults property by using SetupSequence: `feedIteratorMock.SetupSequence(m => m.HasMoreResults)
                .Returns(true)
                .Returns(false);`

Answer (score 4):

You can mock `ReadNextAsync` to return a mock of `FeedResponse` that only has `GetEnumerator()` defined. The `GetEnumerator` of the `List` you create will then be passed through to the underlying implementation of the `foreach`.

The following example uses `Moq`, but you should be able to do something similar in your implementation.

```
var mockFeedResponse = new Mock<FeedResponse<Thing>>();
mockFeedResponse
    .Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator())
    .Returns(
        new List<Thing>
        {
            new Thing(),
            new Thing()
        }.GetEnumerator()
    );
```

Comment: Would be great if you provided a complete answer